# Mockito any vs any(MyClass.class)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I stumbled into the situation when I call `Mockito.when` with any it works but not with
any(MyClass.class).
What is significant difference between these two?
I thought the 2nd version should work just fine and is better.

Comment: Would you share the code? I also currently faced the similar issue, and there was a miss on my code.
```class A extends B { }
any(A.class);```
In this case, if B object is passed, it goes to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.any()` assumes that argument if any type was used like `Object`, `String`, `MyClass`, etc.
`Mockito.any(MyClass.class)` checks that argument of type °MyClass` was passed.
Usually the second version is used more often.
I think that first version is used only when you need to check that a method was called at all.